# Segmentation fault during transcription - DeepSpeech 0.4.1/Spanish

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, mozilla-deepspeech

I am using deepspeech 0.4.1, as instructed by the [Spanish deepspeech github repo](https://github.com/nahuelproietto/deepspeech-spanish-model), on a RedHat 7 server with 64GB RAM in order to transcribe Spanish audio.

I am getting a **“Segmentation Fault"** error shorty after it starts processing.

Here is an example output:

```
-bash-4.2$ deepspeech --model models/output_graph.pb --alphabet models/alphabet.txt --lm models/lm.binary --trie models/trie --audio file.wav
Loading model from file models/output_graph.pb
TensorFlow: v1.12.0-10-ge232881
DeepSpeech: v0.4.1-0-g0e40db6
Warning: reading entire model file into memory. Transform model file into an mmapped graph to reduce heap usage.
2020-01-22 09:21:45.252368: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: FMA
Loaded model in 0.365s.
Loading language model from files models/lm.binary models/trie
Loaded language model in 0.181s.
Running inference.
```

After this line comes the dreaded "**Segmentation Fault**"

I could not find any info about the cause or solution in SO, or in [the deepspeech Mozilla forum](https://discourse.mozilla.org/c/deep-speech/247)

Comment: Thanks. How does it compare to deepspeech?

Comment: Try it and see, it will work for you!